# Prop-types не выдает ошибку в бразере

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Использую Visual Studio Code в консоли браузере нету предупреждения об ошибки  по типу, аналогичный код в codesandbox.io ошибка появляеться. Возможночто что-то отключено в настройках Visual Studio Code предупреждение prop-types, подскажите где это можно посмотреть ?

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

function App({ name=null }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{name}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
App.propsTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.bool,
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Вы же запускаете реакт приложение на своем порту 3000, если там нет ошибок, то их нет. Вск будет показывать ошибки при открытом приложении, т.е. если запустить его из его терминала. Ну если я не ошибаюсь

Comment: все я разобрался в чем ошибка в типе файла, он был .JS, необходимо расширение .TS,  для того что бы проверка типов работала. То есть сервер надо создавать через :

npx create-react-app  --template typescript